# Related function returns error The column either doesn't exist despite two tables having 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables AW_Sales and AWProducts.

AW_Sales

```
OrderDate  OrderNumber  Orderquantity  ProductKey
1-1-2019     SO1          2              P1
```

AWProducts

```
ProductKey ProductCost  ProductPrice  ProductName
P1           200          400           Product1
```

I am trying to create a **new measure `price` in AW_sales table** by trying to replicate product price from the table products.

```
Price = Related(AW_Products[ProductPrice])
```

Error:

> The column 'AW_Products[ProductPrice]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.

The relationship between sales and product table clearly exists

[image]

Comment: Can you please recheck the relationship once again, Because everything seems to be correct from your end. If possible can you post the relationship diagram?

Comment: It not valid to create a measure, that would be for a calculated column, you can then sum. You can just sum your price column and use you realtionship to drive it, you don't need related